# How to implement a transparent proxy over akka http

Tags: akka-http

I need to implement a lightweight sharding service over http using [AKKA HTTP](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/). To illustrate the idea please let me introduce a fake service with only one REST resource list called **/users/**. Customer can create new users by POSTing to the list, or query existing useers by its ID  **/users/:userID**.

The sharding service simply routes to the right shard (concrete service). For POST it creates a new ID and decides which service will handle, for GET or DELETE it gets the ID of the user and routes to the one handling it.

The following image shows how it works.
[image]

I am new to the AKKA HTTP framework, but given the concrete service is already implemented, I just have to implement a sort of transparent proxy in front that will take requests from client, and then forwards the right concrete service according to the routing strategy. 
**Is there any simple implementation in akka that does just that?**

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://github.com/mathieuancelin/akka-http-reverse-proxy/blob/master/src/main/scala/steps/proxy2.scala) is a repo containing a solution that does a round robin for a reverse proxy implemented using akka htttp. A small shange to handle sharding instead will solve this question.